# Conventions adopted for extended reals

Tags: real-numbers, convention, indeterminate-forms

It is known that $0^0$ despite being an indeterminate limit form, is usually defined to be equal to $1$. I wonder whether similar conventions exist for some other "indeterminate forms" in the context of two-point compactifications of real numbers. It would be great if someone showed that some authors used these conventions.

Particularly I am interested to know about usage of the following conventions:

$1^\infty=1$

$0 \cdot \infty=0$

$\infty^0=1$

$\frac 00=0$

I also would be interested whether any author proposed distinguishing between "definable" indeterminate forms (those which can be conveniently defined to have certain value, like $0^0$, $1^\infty$) and those which are more problematic, like $\infty-\infty$ or $\frac\infty\infty$ which cannot be conveniently defined.

Comment: why can't those last two be "conveniently defined" ?

Comment: how is that any different from $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ ??

Comment: @mercio what contradictions appear if we define $0/0=0$?

Comment: because $0 \times 17 = 0$, so whatever value we give to $0/0$ we come to a contradiction $1 = 17$...

Comment: @mercio wrong. if we define 0/0=0, and devide the both parts of $0\cdot 17=0$ by 0, we get 0=0, no contradiction.

Comment: if we define $\infty-\infty = 5$, and substract the both parts of $\infty+1 = \infty$ by $\infty$, we get $5=5$, no contradiction.

Comment: @mercio no, we get 6=5.

Comment: Question also posted to MO, with no notice to either site. Anixx, you should know better than that.

Answer (score 4):

First off, nobody ever *really* means $0^0 = 1$ in a setting where the the exponentiation map $\mathbf{R}_{>0} \times \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ is intended.

There is pretty much always something else going on; e.g. meaning to do arithmetic with *functions* rather than values, and continuously extending the results. That is, in the same settings where you'd write $x/x = 1$ you would also write $x^0 = 1$.

Another common convention is $0 \log 0 = 0$, but that's another example of the same thing: the continuous extension of $x \log x$.

The most widely applicable convention like this I've seen is that of something being "strongly zero". e.g. the Iverson bracket $[P]$ is usually meant to be *strongly* zero whenever $P$ is false. This means that when $P$ is false $[P]$ multiplied by any expression (even an infinite one or even an *undefined* expression) still means zero.